# Comparing two text files on a unix system

Tags: unix, emacs

I am using Emacs on a GNU/Linux system. I am trying to compare two data files containing columns of numbers which are almost similar in content. Is there an Emacs/Unix utility to highlight the differences between these text files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In emacs, if you pull both files into different buffers, you can use the  `M-x ediff-buffers` command to display the differences. Emacs will nicely highlight the differences and allow you to scroll through the buffers concurrently. See tip **#5** on this "[Ten Essential Emacs tips](http://web.psung.name/emacstips/essential.html)" page, or the [GNU docs on Ediff](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ediff/index.html).

Under Unix there's the [`diff`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff) command. Here's a short [example](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/utilities2/diff1.html) of using diff, and [one more example](http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-compare-files-diff.html)

I usually prefer comparing with Emacs, more visual, though of course both files will need to fit into buffers.

Comment: Not that it's much different, but you can also use `M-x ediff-files` so you don't have to open them in buffers first. That being said, I almost always find myself using `ediff-buffers` anyway.

Comment: @gempesaw I usually go for `ediff-buffers` myself too :) .. but it's good to know alternatives, so thanks for mentioning this.

Comment: Can one compare pasted text, not saved files by this technique?

Answer (score 2):

The `diff` command is [your friend.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)